# jmeter http request, beanshell preprocessor output is displayed in square brackets

Tags: jmeter

I am extracting a URL located in the sub sample request, using the jmeter regex. the URL is escaped eg: has `%3D`, `%3F`. To unescape these I used beanshell preprocessor and replaced all these special characters. But when I use this variable(`url`) in the HTTP request its getting parsed with square brackets

code snip of bean shell preprocessor :

```
url = vars.get("escapedUri"); //get escaped url from the regular expression
url = url.replaceAll("%3A", ":");  //replace special characters with :,/,=,?
url = url.replaceAll("%2F", "/");
url = url.replaceAll("%3F", "?");
url = url.replaceAll("%3D", "=");
log.info ("escaped uri chng : " + url);
vars.put("URL", url);
```

The URL when printed in log file is displayed properly :

```
xyz?ID=Login-ID&goto=http://uri/?ReqID=abcdefghijklmnop
```

When I try to use this URL variable in HTTP request sampler is parsing it as follows.

```
https://[xyz?ID=Login-ID&goto=http://uri/?ReqID=abcdefghijklmnop]

jmeter test plan -> 
thread -> 
http request
  -> regex
http request
  -> bean shell preprocessor
```

can you please help me resolving this issue

Comment: also seeing this issue when we use inbuilt  functions "${__urldecode(${escapedUri})}".

Answer (score 1):

My expectation is that you're using that `${URL}` variable in the "Server Name or IP" field when it needs to go to "Path"

[image: URL in PATH]

Also I'm pretty sure that it's possible to get more "clean" URL from the Regular Expression Extractor. Check the following material:

- [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [USING REGULAR EXPRESSION EXTRACTOR](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](http://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Comment: thanks for helping out. the main issue was that we need to split the complete URL . so once we split into server name and path, only then it worked.